# How to delete a specific channel

Tags: discord.js

I am creating a bot that sets up a server when `!setup` is run. I have successfully created the channels I need but I do not know how to delete the default text and voice channels along with their respective categories.

I have not tried anything yet.

I would like the default channels to be deleted once the other channels have been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option would be to find the channels in the guild which have been created at the same time of the guild, then iterate through and delete each.

Example:

```js
const defaultChannels = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.createdTimestamp === message.guild.createdTimestamp);

defaultChannels.forEach(channel => {
  channel.delete()
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and there is an error that originated "by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()"

Comment: There shouldn't be an unhandled promise rejection warning since there's a `catch()` method attached to the promise.

Comment: I have typed the code exactly as it is in your screenshot and it still has this error. There is also another error saying "defaultChannels.forEach is not a function"

Comment: Oops, I just realized I slipped up and used `find()` instead of `filter()`. My bad! Try again with the edited version.